# C++ EXC_BAD_ACCESS of Tree Root Node

Tags: c++, graphics

I'm building an Octree for computer graphics. Trying to build the tree with following code:

```
void Accel::build() {
    Octree *m_octree = new Octree(depth);
    std::vector<uint32_t> indices(triangleCount);
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < triangleCount; ++i) {
        indices[i] = i;
    }
    m_octree->root = m_octree->octreeBuild(m_bbox, indices, m_mesh);
}
```

The tree and tree node class are like the following:

Octree.h

```
class Octree {
public:
        uint32_t totalNodes = 0;
        uint32_t maxDepth = 0;
        uint32_t totalDepth = 0;
        std::vector<OctreeNode *> octreeVector;
        OctreeNode *root;

        Octree();
        Octree(uint32_t d);
        ~Octree();

        OctreeNode *octreeBuild(BoundingBox3f boundingBox, std::vector<uint32_t> indices, Mesh* mesh);
};
```

Octree.cpp

```
Octree::Octree(){}
Octree::Octree(uint32_t d): maxDepth(d) {}
Octree::~Octree(){
}

OctreeNode *Octree::octreeBuild(BoundingBox3f boundingBox, std::vector<uint32_t> indices, Mesh* mesh) {
    if (indices.empty()) {
        OctreeNode *node = nullptr;
        octreeVector.push_back(node);
        return node;
    }

    if (indices.size() <= 10 || totalDepth == maxDepth) {
        OctreeNode *node = new OctreeNode(indices, boundingBox, true);
        octreeVector.push_back(node);
        totalNodes += 1;
        return node;
    }


    if (totalDepth < maxDepth){
        std::vector<uint32_t>  nodeArray[8]; // Eight vector to store child node indices

        BoundingBox3f boxArray[8] = {
            boundingBox, boundingBox, boundingBox, boundingBox, boundingBox, boundingBox, boundingBox, boundingBox
    }; // Eight bounding box, one for each child node

        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 8; ++i) { // Seperate bounding box
            Point3f corner = boundingBox.getCorner(i);
            Point3f center = boundingBox.getCenter();

            Point3f minPoint = Point3f(std::min(corner.x(), center.x()), std::min(corner.y(), center.y()), std::min(corner.z(), center.z()));
            Point3f maxPoint = Point3f(std::max(corner.x(), center.x()), std::max(corner.y(), center.y()), std::max(corner.z(), center.z()));

            boxArray[i] = BoundingBox3f(minPoint, maxPoint);
        }

        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < static_cast<uint32_t>(indices.size()); i++) { // Check overlapping, store indices to cooresponding vector
            BoundingBox3f triangleBox = mesh->getBoundingBox(i);
            for (uint32_t j = 0; j < 8; ++j) {
                if (boxArray[j].overlaps(triangleBox) && boxArray[j].contains(triangleBox.getCenter())) {
                    nodeArray[j].push_back(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        OctreeNode *node = new OctreeNode(indices, boundingBox, false); // Build the new node with children
        octreeVector.push_back(node);
        if (octreeVector.size() == 1) {
            root = node;
        }
        totalDepth += 1;
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
            node->child[i] = octreeBuild(boxArray[i], nodeArray[i], mesh);
            totalNodes += 1;
        }
        return node;
    }

    return nullptr;
};
```

I manage to build the program and the Octree::build went through without error messages. But after trying to search form the tree root, I got the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. It seems like the root of my octree is lost. I'm new to C++, not sure if that's because the algorithms or the way I program with C++ was wrong. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: *I'm new to C++, not sure if that's because the algorithms or the way I program with C++ was wrong* -- That is when you start to do debugging.  Debugging is part and parcel of learning how to write programs.  As to your code, you fail to initialize your member variable `OctTreeNode` when you construct an `OctTree`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at our [help] section](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). See how much of this code you can strip away, and still reproduce the error. In particular, see if a depth of 8 is really necessary, or if you get the same error with a depth of only 7.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies. May I ask for a little bit more details on how I failed to initialize the node and how to solve it? Is that because I store a pointer to a not existing node in the tree, or something else? I tried to solve on my own but was lost for quite a while...

Comment: @fs254 -- The way to solve it is to initialize the node to something valid or `nullptr` when you construct the `OctTree`.  You will see quite quickly that this is a problem when you finally get around writing a proper destructor for `OctTree` (that current empty destructor doesn't clean up the memory) , and your destructor causes issues for the simplest of cases, i.e. `int main() { OctTree t; }`  A 1-line program like that will cause issues.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hi Paul, I updated my destructor and initialization. And tried to print `(m_octree->root != nullptr)` in `Accel::build()`, then another method in Accel. It turns out that in `Accel::build()`, `(m_octree->root != nullptr)` returns 1, and in the method which uses `m_octree->root`, the EXC_BAD_ACCESS happens. I do initialize that as `Octree *m_octree = nullptr` in Accel; May I have your opinion for why it happens like that?

Comment: `m_octtree->root` -- The `m_octree` itself has to be valid / non-null before using `->`.